# Парсер данных в кольцевом буфере

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Программирую `STM32` на `C\C++`, имеется кольцевой буфер входящих данных (не важно, текстовых или бинарных). Естественно известен формат данных, которые поступают, разделители и все прочее. Буфер имеет размер много меньше, чем принимаемый пакет данных, поэтому ловить конец пакета, и только после этого парсить пакет не вариант. Необходим именно динамический парсер данных. На ум приходит следующий вариант: объявляем переменную, которая указывает этап парсинга, и в цикле while оператора switch постепенно переключаемся между этапами парсинга.

```
uint8_t Stage;
bool PacketProcess;

PacketProcess = false;
while (!PacketProcess)
{
  switch (Stage)
  {
    case 0: // ожидаем появления в буфере команды
      if (в буфере есть команда)
      {
        принимаем команду;
        Stage = 1;
      }
      break;
    case 1: // ожидаем появления в буфере разделителя (например запятая)
      if (в буфере есть разделитель)
      {
        считываем разделитель;
        Stage = 2;
      }
      break;
    case 2: // ожидаем появления в буфере данных 1
      if (в буфере есть данные 1)
      {
        принимаем данные 1;
        Stage = 3;
      }
      break;
    case 3: // ожидаем появления в буфере разделителя (например запятая)
      if (в буфере есть разделитель)
      {
        считываем разделитель;
        Stage = 4;
      }
    case 4: // ожидаем появления в буфере данных 2
      if (в буфере есть данные 2)
      {
        принимаем данные 2;
        Stage = 5;
      }
      break;
    case 5: // ожидаем появления в буфере конца пакета
      if (в буфере есть конец пакета)
      {
        считываем конец пакета;
        Stage = 0;
        PacketProcess = true;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

При увеличении команд парсер распухает в геометрической прогрессии. 

Вопрос собственно в следующем: как грамотней организовать алгоритм?

Comment: Ну общий вид все равно такой примерно будет. можно как то оптимизировать. правда для этого надо видеть что такое "ожидаем" и что в if написано. действия же однотипные, значит теоретически их можно как то формализовать и записать в виде таблицы адрес ячейки в которой это Stage, а в ячейке лежит структура описывающая ожидаемое, например размер ожидаемых данных, адрес функции проверки корректности содержимого, номер следующего Stage если ok и номер если ошибка.

Comment: И кстати кольцевой буфер и доступен весь пакет сразу или нет значения особого не имеет. Большинство синтаксических анализаторов - конечные автоматы. То что вы написали - типичный конечный автомат. Есть даже генераторы синтаксических анализаторов, вроде `bison` или `yacc` которые по описанию входного языка (обычно в BNF и его расширениях) сами создают примерно такой C код

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, парсить подструктуры в пакете, желательно делая их маленькими, и парьсить что пришло, а не ожидать строгий порядок данных. Важно, чтобы буфер был размером с самую большую структуру + запас на входящие данные пока вы парсите.
Было бы проще, если бы был указан примерный формат пакета.
Я бы делал парсер по такому подобию:

```
enum structureMarker {part_one, part_two, part_three, etc};

pasePartOne(ptr* begin, ptr* end, dataStructOne& data)
{
    // ... some parsing logic
}


while(hasdata())
{
    if(isSubDataDelimeter(pDataHead))
    {
        switch(getMarkerType(pParsedTail+1))
        {
            case part_one: pasePartOne(pParsedTail+1, pDataHead, fullstruct.one); break;
            case part_two: ... /// etc
            ... /// etc
        }
    }
}
```

чтобы избавиться от распухания кода парсера нужно либо делать парсинг самых простых типов объединенных в что-то типа структур с ключами (но это дает оверхед), но зато парсеров будет меньше. 
Тип подструктуры можно определять по размеру(не очень, но "хитрый финт"), либо по первому байту. Таким образом код парсера будет по-проще.

Answer (score 0):

Может так:

```
struct element el;

while (1) {
    GetElement(&el);
    if ( TypOfElement(&el) ==  END_OF_PKT) break;
    if ( TypOfElement(&el) ==  DELIMITER) continue;
    if ( TypOfElement(&el) ==  DATA) PackData(&el);
}
```

Comment: какой то бред... GetElement читает, а потом if проверяет... нужно наоборот, сначала убедится, что данные нужного размера присутствуют в буфере, а потом только их читать

Comment: **нужно наоборот, сначала убедится, что данные нужного размера присутствуют в буфере** - функция *GetElement* - блокирующая. Сталкивались с таким термином? Она ВИСИТ до тех пор, пока нет данных в буфере.  Если блокирующий подход Вас не устраивает, Вам придётся воспользоваться многопоточным решением.

Comment: я использую RTOS и все равно не желаю использовать блокирующие функции, хотя это и позволительно в моем случае

Comment: **не желаю использовать блокирующие функции** а разве вот этот текст: *// ожидаем появления в буфере* не Вы написали?! ОЖИДАНИЕ ПОЯВЛЕНИЯ - это ведь и есть - блокирующий ввод!